# Java 64 bit JDK question

Tags: java, 64-bit

If I compile some java files using a 64 bit JDK and then make a JAR file out of them will the resultant JAR correctly work with a 32 bit JRE, or do I have to use a 32 bit JDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The resultant JAR will correctly work with a 32 bit JRE.  You do not need to recompile your jar.